# Hibernate takes so much time to load on application run

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

Hibernate is getting stuck when i run my application using ddl-auto 'update' or 'validate'

I have a local Oracle DataBase with a user (TEST) running on port 1521.

On the Spring application I have this on my application yml config file:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
  devtools:
    add-properties: true
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test'
    username: 'TEST'
    password: 'Testing123'
    driverClassName: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: "update"
      dialect: 'org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect'
```

When I run the application it gets stuck on these lines:

```
2019-07-19 13:30:39.043  INFO 74584 [  restartedMain] o.h.Version                              : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-07-19 13:30:39.045  INFO 74584 [  restartedMain] o.h.c.Environment                        : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-07-19 13:30:39.235  INFO 74584 [  restartedMain] o.h.a.c.r.j.JavaReflectionManager        : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-07-19 13:30:39.475  INFO 74584 [  restartedMain] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : Test-H2DBPool - Starting...
2019-07-19 13:30:40.750  INFO 74584 [  restartedMain] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : Test-H2DBPool - Start completed.
2019-07-19 13:30:40.769  INFO 74584 [  restartedMain] o.h.d.Dialect                            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

If I change the hibernate ddl-auto to 'create-drop' it works perfect and it doesn't get stuck.

I tried to debug the application and I've tried to get some logs, but nothing is showing and I don't know what I could do. With 'create-drop' i get the SQL logs without problem.

Edit:

After waiting 40 minutes with the application running it has been executed and running well.

If I use the user SYS as SYSDBA when I run the application, Hibernate loads in 40 seconds more or less. Why with another user it takes so much time to load?

Comment: Try disabling second level cache. In your app properties set this - hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false. Take a look at this for more details on how to enable disable second level cache - https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache

Comment: I've disabled the second level cache, but it still takes a lot of time loading. With the user SYS as SYSDBA it took 68 seconds to load the application. With the other user it took a lot of time again.

Comment: What version of OraDB and ojdbc jar you are using? If using 12.x DB, trying using the latest dialect and latest ojdbc.

Comment: I'm using 19.c. I've tried using org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect and org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect but happens the same with both.

Comment: I am using 19c and got the same problem, I guess it's related to the user set-up (in my case at least). I used one of the predefined users (ANONYMOUS), restarted my app and it worked.